# "Disable" line with the lowest value for specific argument in time (visualisation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, plotly, googlevis

I have not trivial problem with data visualization. Let's suppose I have data set as below

```
set.seed(11)
data <- data.frame(
    nr = rep(1:5, 3),
    group = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5)),
    value = sample(15, replace = TRUE)
)
```

The simplest plot from it using `plotly` looks like this

```
library(plotly) 
plot_ly(data, x = ~nr, y = ~value) %>% 
    add_lines(color = ~group)
```

[image]

I use `plotly` to make my plot interactive with user. When the user hovers the mouse on specific point on x axis I want to display only two lines with the hightes value at this specific point (the third line should be transparent or colored in some other color (grey for example)). As the user change the position of the mouse the colors of the line should be updated. For example when x = 2 I want to change the color of the green line since it has the lowest value in point x = 2.

[image]

And if the user move the mouse to the point x = 3 the green line should be again be visible and the red line should be grey

[image]

And so on. Do you know how to do it?
I user `plotly` but if you now any other package which can do it it's no problem for me to use some other package.

Comment: You could probably do it in R by reacting to the `plotly_hover` event. Then just redraw the entire plot anyway you want (highlighting anything you want to) depending on what point came over. Or you could do it in javascript which would give you more options.